# recyclerView setOnScrollChangeListener = need api 23 (current min is 15)

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);
```

The problem is that android studio Call requires `API level 23 (current min is 15)`

I found similar questions but with no right answer.

how can I solve this error?

Comment: You either only support devices v23 or later, or you find a different way of doing what you're trying to do.  And without knowing what you're doing in/why you're using a scroll change listener we can't help you with that.

Comment: Why don't you use an OnScrollListener insted? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html

Comment: thank you friends!

Comment: For `NestedScrollView` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832043/nestedscrollview-setonscrollchangelistener-api-21.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try implementing an `onScrollListener` instead. This is dependent on what you are implementing in your scroll events but if you are simply looking for something that is backward compatible to your min of **15** this would be the choice:

```
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        // onScrollStateChanged will be fire every time you scroll
        // Perform your operation here

        }
    }
```