# NestedScrollView setOnScrollChangeListener api 21

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview, onscrolllistener

Hello folks I'm trying to handle an `onScrolled` event in my `recyclerView`, that's inside a `NestedScrollView`.

So far, I have found `setOnScrollChangeListener`, however this method is API 23, and I'm targeting API 21, any idea to handle this issue back in API 21?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time I got an idea, I've stopped listening to scroll on `RecyclerView` and started listening to `NestedScrollView` `onScroll` event.

I managed to make my loadOnDemand `recyclerView` using this snippet

```
    nsv_posts_timeline.setOnScrollChangeListener(
            NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener {
                                _, scrollX, scrollY, _, oldScrollY ->

        if(scrollY > oldScrollY){
            val totalItens = timelineAdapter.itemCount

            val currentView = rv_timeline.findChildViewUnder(scrollX.toFloat(), scrollY.toFloat())
            val childPosition = rv_timeline.getChildAdapterPosition(currentView)

            if((totalItens/2) - (stepSize/2) <= childPosition && !isLoading){
                isLoading = true
                                          //skip , take
                timelinePresenter.loadMore(totalItens, 5)
            }
        }
    })
```

`isLoading` is a class property that I change to false when my callback returns from server

Answer (score 25):

I think you are using setOnChangeScrollListener with View.OnScrollChangeListener.
Please use NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener like that:

```
 scvProduct.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView nestedScrollView,int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

            Log.e("ProductFragment","position button " + topPositionButton + " scrollY " + scrollY);
            if(scrollY > oldScrollY){
                Log.e("ProductFragment","down");
            }
            else{
                Log.e("ProductFragment","up");
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: image compare NestedScrollview and View OnScrollChangeListener]

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that using ViewTreeObserver#addOnScrollChangedListener() below api 23:

```
mRecylerview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
      @Override public void onScrollChanged() {
          int x = toolbar.getScrollX();
          int y = toolbar.getScrollY();
      }
    });
```

Comment: I'm inside a fragment, any idea how to get Y from fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @NhatVM in Kotlin:

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(
    NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener { nestedScrollView, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY ->
        // ...
    }
)
```